# Are grouped CSS rules treated differently than specifying separate rules for each selector?

Tags: css

The following is two nearly identical XHTML documents with slightly different CSS.  In my understanding, grouping selectors is only for convenience, and shouldn't have an effect on their application, however these two documents produce different renderings?  Am I confused?

First with selectors grouped

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<title>An XHTML 1.0 Strict standard template</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type"
    content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

<style type="text/css">
    #container {
        background-color : #000000;
        color : #000000;
    }
    a, a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {
        color : #000000;
    }
    .link {
        color : #FFFFFF;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
<a href="#" class="link">Testing</a><br /><a href="#" class="link">Testing</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

-----=====Versus=====-----
Separate selectors

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<title>An XHTML 1.0 Strict standard template</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type"
    content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

<style type="text/css">
    #container {
        background-color : #000000;
        color : #000000;
    }
    a {
        color : #000000;
    }
    a:visited {
        color : #000000;
    }
    a:hover {
        color : #000000;
    }
    a:active {
        color : #000000;
    }
    .link {
        color : #FFFFFF;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
<a href="#" class="link">Testing</a><br /><a href="#" class="link">Testing</a>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: They're not equal. The first block contains `a:link`, whereas the second block doesn't contain this selector.

Comment: What are the differences you see? What browsers have you tried?

Comment: They don't have the same `doctype` either.

Comment: @GoodEnough Actually, they do. Markdown was hiding it.

Comment: @GoodEnough how do you know they dont have the same doctype

Comment: You're right, I missed the a:link

Comment: And missed indenting the doctype (but you missed the missing <html> tag)

Answer (score 1):

You're hitting an issue of selector weight - in your first example, you have

```
a:link, a:hover {
  color: black;
}
a {
  color: red;
}
```

This will make `<a>` always black, because `a:link` *IS* `a` - but it has a higher weight with css - just like `.someClass a` would out-rank `a`.

In the second example, you aren't over-weighting `a`, and thus having it below the `a:hover` rules overrides it.

Here's an article about understanding this concept: http://css-tricks.com/855-specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: @Obed - From my fiddle I see that there IS a difference?

Answer (score 0):

You are not misunderstanding CSS and the two examples you presented are effectively the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is the difference I see:

http://jsfiddle.net/sCKHP/2/

In the first example `.link` has precedence over `a:link`

In the second example `a:link` has precedence over `.link`